# Install package with apt-get and remove with aptitude?

Tags: apt, aptitude

Anything wrong with this practice? would it work?

If I install package with `apt-get` and remove with `aptitude`?

In addition, I recently removed webmin. Does `apt-get --purge remove` also delete dependencies installed during `apt-get install webmin`?

How do I check for those and remove if it didn't get removed automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can freely use `apt-get` and `aptitude` intermixed, because both of them do the same thing behind the scenes - manipulate the `dpkg` package management system (the back-end to `apt` utilities).

`aptitude` remove automatically unneeded packages by default.

With `apt-get` you should pass the `--auto-remove` option to obtain the same behavior, or use `apt-get autoremove` alone.